# How to select option class/value with jquery in select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide/show div based on select drop-down option value/class click. But i am unable to select do that because Chrome not supporting this functionality. Could anyone please help me to find out a simple way with that i can write jquery script on click for option class/value. On web i found that on click function does not work in chrome.

Here is my code.

```
<select id="dd1" style="width: 12%">
<option class="all" value="all">Select below 1</option>
<option id="opt1" class="opt1" value="opt1">option 1</option>
<option class="opt2" value="opt2">option 2</option>
<option class="opt3" value="opt3">option 3</option>
<option class="opt4" value="opt4">option 4</option>
</select>

<select id="dd2" style="width: 12%">
<option value="all">Select below 1</option>
<option class="opt5" value="opt5">option 5</option>
<option  class="opt6" value="opt6">option 6</option>
<option class="opt7" value="opt7">option 7</option>
<option class="opt8" value="opt8">option 8</option>
</select>

here is the jquery code

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.opt1').on('click',function(){

$('.modal1, .modal2, .modal3, .modal4, .modal5, .modal6, .modal7, .modal8, .modal9, .modal10, .modal11, .modal12, .modal13, .modal14, .modal15, .modal16, .modal17, .modal18, .modal19, .modal20, .modal21, .modal23, .modal24, .modal25, .modal26').show();    
$('.modal22').hide();

$("#dd2 option[value='2']").remove();

}); 

$('.fids1').on('click',function(){
$('.modal22').show();
$('.modal1, .modal2, .modal3, .modal4, .modal5, .modal6, .modal7, .modal8, .modal9, .modal10, .modal11, .modal12, .modal13, .modal14, .modal15, .modal16, .modal17, .modal18, .modal19, .modal20, .modal21, .modal23, .modal24, .modal25, .modal26').hide();    


$("#dd2 option[value='2']").remove();

}); 

});
```

Comment: Your selector should be `$("#dd2 option[value='opt1']").remove();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about it the wrong way:

```
$('.opt1').on('click',function(){
  //...
});
```

You don't want to perform an action *when the `<option/>` is "clicked"*.  Instead, you want to perform an action *when the `<select/>` value is changed to a specific value*.

Something like this:

```
$('#dd1').on('change',function(){
  if ($(this).val() === 'opt1') {
    //...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you David, but i tried this code & it still not working, i need code that can select options & based on option click div will hide/show.

Comment: @MrSingh: What is your updated code and how specifically is it not working as expected?  Is the event handler triggered?  Does it find the value?  Does it compare the value successfully?  What fails?

Comment: Many Many thanks David, you made my day, Great help. Really big thank you sir. It is working fine now. (i just removed one (=).